# MongoDB Rename Collection - Did not use Admin Collection

Tags: mongodb

I ran the command:

```
> db.documents.renameCollection({ renameCollection: "documents", to: "documents_backup" });
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

My 'documents_backup' collection wasn't created. My 'documents' collection was emptied.

I realized I did not pay attention to an important detail in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/renameCollection/). This command was supposed to be ran on the 'admin' collection, not my collection.

Is this recoverable? Or, did the data simply vanish? The 'ok' response is a little misleading.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, the Collection was re-named "[object Object]" and the fix was relatively simple:

```
> db["[object Object]"].renameCollection('documents_backup')
{ "ok" : 1 }
```